# I can't get this virtual templated functor operator to return the correct type

Tags: c++, templates, generics, virtual

I've been at this for a long time. Basically the class takes in a type, which will probably be a function, and also some arguments:

```
template <typename T, typename ... Args>
struct HandlerBase
{
    HandlerBase(T type, Args ... args) {}
    HandlerBase() {}

     auto operator()(Args ... args) 
        { return std::declval<T>()(args...); }  ;
};// This compiles
```

But now I want to make my operator() virtual, and I get the error:

> "a virtual member function shall not have a return type that contains
>   auto".

So I need to manually put the return type, and the best I could try after all my searching is:

```
virtual decltype(std::declval<T>()(std::declval<Args>()...)) 
operator()(Args ... args)
{ return std::declval<T>()(args...); }  ;
```

Or as a trailing return

```
virtual auto operator()(Args ... args)
-> decltype(std::declval<T>()(std::declval<Args>()...))
{ return std::declval<T>()(args...); }  ;
```

These attempts are based on some help I got earlier about this topic. I really find it nearly impossible to parse through a statement like this.

This is what the whole thing looks like in case anyone wants to try it:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
struct HandlerBase
{
    HandlerBase(T type, Args ... args) {}
    HandlerBase() {}

     virtual decltype(std::declval<T>()(std::declval<Args>()...)) operator()(Args ... args)
        { return std::declval<T>()(args...); }  ;
};

int main()
{
    auto lambda = []() { return 0; };
    HandlerBase<decltype(lambda)> object;   
}
```

On Visual Studio in both normal return syntax and trailing return syntax I get the error I get a linker error which is basically unreadable, but it mentions something about an the return type being int, so I think my actual definition inside the brackets might be wrong.

Comment: On IDEOne it says "/usr/include/c++/6/type_traits:2270:7: error: static assertion failed: declval() must not be used!
       static_assert(__declval_protector<_Tp>::__stop,

Answer (score 2):

`std::declval` is only ever meant to be used in an unevaluated context. As its [documentation on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) reads:

> Note that because no definition exists for declval, it can only be
>   used in unevaluated contexts; it is an error to evaluate an expression
>   that contains this function. Formally, the program is ill-formed if
>   this function is odr-used.

When you write `std::declval<T>()(args...)` it attempts to call the function call operator using the reference `declval` returns. That's an odr-use, the linker must look it up. And it can't find it, hence the error.

It's triggered only when you add the virtual specifier, because virtual functions are implicitly odr-used (mainly because they have to be in order to add dynamic dispatch support).

Without the virtual specifier, the function body of your `operator()` is never instantiated until an attempt is made to call it (on account `HandlerBase<>` being a template class). But you'd get the exact same linker error if you try to call `operator()` in your original "working" version.

Comment: I just realised if I change one thing, that is HandlerBase<decltype(lambda)> object; to object(); //with brackets when instantiating it, it works. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement what you desire by using the standard result_of

```
typename std::result_of<T(Args...)>::type
```

The entire things looks like this:

```
template <typename T, typename ... Args>
struct HandlerBase
{
    HandlerBase(T type, Args ... args) {}
    HandlerBase() {}

    virtual auto operator()(Args ... args)
    -> typename std::result_of<T(Args...)>::type
    { return T()(std::forward<Args>(args)...); };
};
```

**Edited**

As pointed out, `std::result_of` was replaced in c++17 by `std::invoke_result`.

Here is an alternative implementation using `std::invoke` and `std::invoke_result`:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
struct HandlerBase
{
    HandlerBase() {}

    virtual auto operator()(T type, Args ... args)
    -> typename std::invoke_result_t<T, Args...>
    { return std::invoke(type, args...); };
};

int main()
{
    auto lambda = []() { return 0; };
    HandlerBase<decltype(lambda)> object;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I though std::result_of is deprecated. I'll try this though. I still don't know what story teller was saying about the ODR rule and the linker not finding it.